# How to install a Huawei EC-226 USB Modem?

Tags: huawei

Someone could tellme how to install the USB modem Huawei EC-226

Comment: You're qeustion number 100000

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide at Ubuntuforums. Have a look here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1090119
Maybe it helps You :